# Is my casting wrong?

Tags: c++

```
void xGetFunctionAddress(void* FunctionDefinition, std::string FunctionName)
{
    *static_cast<FARPROC*>(FunctionDefinition) = xProcAddress(Module, FunctionName.c_str());
}
```

In the above code, I'm trying to get rid of that `FARPROC*` to make it cross-platform. However, if I cast to `long long int (*)()`, it gives me the error that it cannot statically cast to that. So when I typedef it, it works:

Ex:

```
//This works:
void xGetFunctionAddress(void* FunctionDefinition, std::string FunctionName)
{
    typedef __stdcall long long int (*Ptr)();
    *static_cast<Ptr*>(FunctionDefinition) = GetProcAddress(Module, FunctionName.c_str());
}

//This doesn't:
void xGetFunctionAddress(void* FunctionDefinition, std::string FunctionName)
{
    *static_cast<long long int(*)()>(FunctionDefinition) = GetProcAddress(Module, FunctionName.c_str());
}
```

What am I doing wrong in the second example? :S

Comment: What tis the return type of `xProcAddress()`?

Comment: It returns FARPROC's signature. Aka typedef __int64 (__stdcall *FARPROC)();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are casting the void pointer to a function pointer and then dereferencing it. This evaluates to an assignment to a function instead of a function pointer. The following should take of the problem

```
*static_cast<long long int(__stdcall **)()>(FunctionDefinition) = GetProcAddress(Module, FunctionName.c_str());
                                     ^^
```

Notice the additional pointer level next to `__stdcall`.

Comment: Wow.. That Magic! I never knew that was what was happening. So if I remove the dereference it would have worked?

Comment: No, because it would then evaluated to an rvalue.

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to see the specific error message, but it looks like you might be missing the __stdcall dcl-specifier in your static_cast. Does it work if you add that?

Edit:

Looking further, it appears this may not be supported. Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1096349/279130 which seems to address the same question.

Comment: No I tried that too. error: invalid static_cast from type 'void*' to type 'long long int (*)() with and without the __stdcall Changing it to the typedef gives no problems at all..

Comment: OK. Did some additional research. Modifying answer above.

Answer (score 1):

What is GetProcAddress() defined to return?

If it's a `void *`, you can't portably cast that to a function pointer.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1096349/37386

Comment: FARPROC that is something like void(*)(void)