# can void* be used to store function pointers?

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers, void-pointers

void* is defined in such a way that it could point any thing. So can it be used to point a function (int send())?

```
int send();
void* p = send;
```

Is it possible? When i use like this it is not showing me errors why? If not, Is there any way to store all pointers in a single variable?

Comment: No, void* is incompatible to function pointers

Comment: I think it is possible

Comment: `void*` is defined to be able to hold any *data*-pointer. Function-pointers (and for C++ member-pointers) are completely different animals. Though POSIX allows assigning a function-pointer to a `void*` (It is even listed as a common extension in the C standard `J.5.7 Function pointer casts`).

Comment: It being possible in any particular implementation (say on x86 where most compilers can) does not mean that the standard allows it (which I believe it does not).

Comment: @dmckee Actually, it's on x86 where I've had the most problems with it.  Think of the old far/near issues, and the compilation models where function pointers were far, but data pointers near, or vice versa.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No it may not.

According to the C Standard (6.3.2.3 Pointers)

> 1 A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any
>   **object type**. A pointer to any **object type** may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to
>   the original pointer.

As for function pointers then

> 8 A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to
>   a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare
>   equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call
>   a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the
>   behavior is undefined.

In the C++ Standard there is more detailed definition of pointers (3.9.2 Compound types)

> 3 The type of **a pointer to void** or a pointer to an object type is
>   called an **object pointer type**....The type of a pointer that can
>   designate a function is called a **function pointer type**.

And

> 4 **A pointer to cv-qualified (3.9.3) or cv-unqualified void** can be used
>   to point to o**bjects** of unknown type. Such a pointer shall be able to
>   hold any object pointer. An object of type cv void* shall have the
>   same representation and alignment requirements as cv char*.

Comment: A function is no object type (you may but it into a lambda, though)

Comment: The quoted passages only apply to C, of course.  The rules in C++ are different.

Comment: However POSIX does require the conversion to be defined, and for them to have the same size and representation, as part of the needs of `dlsym`.

Comment: "No it may not." Nowhere in your quotes does it say "it may not"; it just doesn't say "it may".

Comment: @newacct Thanks. I will know now that "may not" is not the same as "do not may".

Comment: @R Now.  Earlier versions of Posix were somewhat ambiguous about the issue, and the example code used something like `*(void**)ptr = dlsym(...);`.

Comment: @newacct In C, I'm not sure, but I think the conversion is undefined behavior (which means that an implementation is free to define it).  At least, the C standard doesn't seem to require a diagnostic; it just doesn't define any behavior for it (which makes it undefined behavior).

Answer (score 21):

Maybe.  Until C++11, they couldn't; but C++11 adds:

> Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is
>   conditionally-supported. The meaning of such a conversion is
>   implementation-defined, except that if an implementation supports
>   conversions in both directions, converting a prvalue of one type to the
>   other type and back, possibly with different cvqualification, shall
>   yield the original pointer value.

This doesn't appear to have made it into C yet.

The reason why you can't convert between them, of course, is because
they may not have the same size or format.  Posix requires that they do
have the same size and format, and I would expect all Posix compilers to
support the conversion; most did before anyway, even though it made them
non-conformant.

EDIT:

A little more information.  After rereading the C standard, I think
conversions between object pointers and function pointers are undefined
behavior: the C standard doesn't seem to require a diagnostic in this
case, but it definitely doesn't define any behavior for it.  As
undefined behavior, an implementation (or Posix) is free to define it.
Or just do anything it wants, without documenting it.

On the otherhand, C++, pre C++11, *required* a diagnostic (although
a number of compilers didn't give one).  In C++11, as per the paragraph
quoted above, it is implementation defined whether an implementation
supports it or not, and if an implementation supports it, they are
required to document its behavior.  So in all cases, an implementation
is required to document what it does, and if it does not support it, it
is required to issue a diagnostic if the code tries to do the
conversion.

Comment: This is closest to the correct answer, the accepted answer is wrong. For standard C it is undefined, for POSIX C it is defined as possible and for C++11 it is defined as above. GCC for one definitely supports this.

Comment: @sjdowling: I see no downvotes on the accepted answer. If you think it's wrong, why have you not downvoted it?

Comment: @sjdowling The accepted answer is correct for C, as far as the ISO standard is concerned.  (Posix contradicts the ISO standard for the C language in several places.)