# How to cast void* to a function pointer?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, freertos

I am using xTaskCreate in FreeRTOS whose 4th parameter (void * const) is the parameter to pass to the function invoked by the new Thread.

```
void __connect_to_foo(void * const task_params) {
   void (*on_connected)(void);
   on_connected = (void) (*task_params);
   on_connected();
}

void connect_to_foo(void (*on_connected)(void)) {
   // Start thread
   xTaskCreate(
         &__connect_to_foo,
         "ConnectTask",
         STACK_SIZE,
         (void*) on_connected, // params
         TASK_PRIORITY,
         NULL // Handle to the created Task - we don't need it.
         );
}
```

I need to be able to pass in a function pointer with signature

> void bar();

But I can't work out how to cast void* to a function pointer that I can invoke. Closest I can get is:

> error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type on line 3

How can I cast task_params to a function pointer that I can invoke?

NB the code above is grossly simplified.

Comment: BTW, [casts from to pointers-to-functions to `void*` (and back) aren't necessarily allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917194/can-void-be-used-to-store-function-pointers) (although supporting it is a common extension).  Also, [symbols that start with a double underscore are reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: The use of the double underscore in identifiers is reserved

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
typedef void (*OnConnected_t)();
OnConnected_t on_connected = OnConnected_t(task_params);
on_connected();
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an portable alternative to a direct cast. A pointer to a function pointer is itself a data pointer. That is to say, given `auto connect_to_foo_ptr = &__connect_to_foo`, `void* ptr = &connect_to_foo_ptr` is legal everywhere.

Of course, to call it, you'll need to cast the `void*` back to a `void (**)(void * const task_params)`, and dereference it twice. The first dereference gets you back the function pointer, the second gets you the original function.

One restriction here is that you need to assure that `connect_to_foo_ptr` doesn't go out of scope, but that's usually not a problem. You can usually make it `static`, but even that is not needed for the common callback pattern.