# Cannot pass shared_ptr argument to function pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, smart-pointers

I have a problem with the code that uses function pointer that takes shared_ptr argument.

Here is a sample code.

header.h

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
template <class T> class FuncWrapper{
    private:
        void (*original_function)(T a);
    public:
        void setFunction(void *func);
        void execFunction(T a, void *data);
};

template <class T> void FuncWrapper<T>::setFunction(void *func){
    original_function = (void (*)(T))func;
}

template <class T> void FuncWrapper<T>::execFunction(T a, void *data){   
    FuncWrapper<T>* wrapper = (FuncWrapper<T>*)data;
    std::cout << "inside wrapper " << *(a.get()) << std::endl;
    wrapper->original_function(a);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "header.h"

class ClassA{
    public:
        ClassA(std::shared_ptr<int> a){
            FuncWrapper<std::shared_ptr<int>> *fw;
            fw = new FuncWrapper<std::shared_ptr<int>>;
            fw->setFunction((void*)&ClassA::print_int);
            std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<int>)> g = std::bind(&FuncWrapper<std::shared_ptr<int>>::execFunction, fw, std::placeholders::_1, fw);
            g(a);
            delete fw;
        }
    private:
        void print_int(std::shared_ptr<int> x) {
            std::cout << "printing int" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "given int " << *(x.get()) << std::endl;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    std::shared_ptr<int> x = std::make_shared<int>(10);
    std::cout << "inside main " << *(x.get()) << std::endl;
    ClassA *temp;
    temp = new ClassA(x);
    delete temp;
    return 0;
}
```

Result

```
inside main 10
inside wrapper 10
printing int
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I cannot figure out why it causes segmentation fault.

Changing `std::shared_ptr<int>` to `int` works just fine.
Therefore I assume that it has to do with owenership of shared_ptr, but I'm not familiar with smart pointers and I'm completely at loss.

I want to know

- why it does not work
- how to make it work

Limitations are

- w/o changing `print_int` function itself
- execute function within `FuncWrapper<T>::execFunction`
- `FuncWrapper<T>::execFunction` has to be static

Otherwise, it is free to change. (inside `ClassA` constructor, inside `main` `execFunction` etc.)

Comment: In which line do you get the segmentation fault?

Comment: ```std::cout << "given int " << *(x.get()) << std::endl;```
this line
because somehow address of ```x``` returns 0x1

Comment: I think this the problem `wrapper->original_function(a);`. It causes undefined behavior after `fw->setFunction((void*)&ClassA::print_int);`

Comment: `fw->setFunction((void*)&ClassA::print_int);` is not a `(void (*)(T))` type, but rather a `(void (*)(ClassA*, T))` type. I suggest you to avoid the cast to `void*` and make `setFunction` take an argument of `(void (*)(T))` type and you will se the error.

Comment: If you have to use a C style cast to make your code compile your code is probably wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the shared_ptr, but mismatch between pointers to a function and a member function.

Your function wrapper expects a pointer to a function (`void (*)(std::shared_ptr<int>)`), but you provide a pointer to a member function (`void (ClassA::*)(std::shared_ptr<int>)`), which is different. An implicit leading argument of pointer to this is added to it.

This is how it really looks like:

```
// pointer to member function
void (*)(ClassA *ptr, std::shared_ptr<int>)
```

Your shared_ptr goes to the first argument and fortunately the application segfaults.

One of the solutions is to make the function `print_int` static.

```
class ClassA{
    public:
        ClassA(std::shared_ptr<int> a){
            FuncWrapper<std::shared_ptr<int>> *fw;
            fw = new FuncWrapper<std::shared_ptr<int>>;
            fw->setFunction((void*)&ClassA::print_int);
            std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<int>)> g = std::bind(&FuncWrapper<std::shared_ptr<int>>::execFunction, fw, std::placeholders::_1, fw);
            g(a);
            delete fw;
        }

    private:
        static void print_int(std::shared_ptr<int> x) {
            std::cout << "printing int" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "given int " << *(x.get()) << std::endl;
        }
};
```

But there seems to be another problem in your code. Function pointers should not be converted to object pointers (which void * is). Maybe change your setFunction this way:

```
void setFunction(void (*func)(T)) {
        original_function = func;
}
```

More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917194/can-void-be-used-to-store-function-pointers/26917282#26917282)

Comment: Indeed ```print_int``` should be static, so your solution is exactly what I wanted. Huge Thanks.