# Possible convert a llvm::FunctionType to C/C++ raw function pointer?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-c++-api

Can we convert [llvm::FunctionType](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1FunctionType.html)'s object into a C/C++-styled function raw pointer?

A example for a C/C++-styled function raw pointer: `uint64_t (*funPtr)(uint64_t* args);`

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Calling such pointer would cause UB.

Comment: @arrowd I would like to construct a llvm::Function. Then to call it in order to have the return value: in our example the `uint64_t`.

Answer (score 2):

`llvm::Function` is represented as an abstract syntax tree. You can't call it, just like you can't call arrays, lists, or any other data structures.

Instead, you need to leverage LLVM's `ExecutionEngine` functionality to be able to call `llvm::Function`s. Internally, the engine will compile it into native executable code and return a `void*` (I don't remember the API details, but something like that) to that code. Then you will be able to cast this pointer to a function pointer and finally use it to call the function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure with regards to the capabilities of `llvm`, but this text from [n4659](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) may be helpful:

> Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported. The meaning of such a conversion is implementation-defined, except that if an implementation supports conversions in both directions, converting a prvalue of one type to the other type and back, possibly with different cv-qualification, shall yield the original pointer value.

I'm pretty sure that *function pointers* aren't like regular pointers, and so these conversions are problematic.  I think they discuss the issue at length in this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096341/function-pointers-casting-in-c).